# Giant series of errors when deploying Hubot

Tags: github, chatbot, hubot, campfire

I am installing hubot on Linux, and followed [the instructions](https://github.com/github/hubot/wiki/Deploying-Hubot-onto-UNIX), receiving no errors.

However, when I try to actually run my hubot, I encounter problems. First I tried daemonizing hubot according the the instructions at the very end of the linked tutorial. `start hubot` returned the error `start: Unknown job: hubot`. So I backed up and tried `/opt/hubot/bin/hubot --name Ro\ Bot --adapter campfire` and got this series of errors:

```
 /opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 11: Hubot: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 12: Fs: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 13: Path: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 14: HTTP: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 15: Creator: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 16: OptParse: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 18: Switches: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 19: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 20: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 21: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 22: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 23: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 24: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 25: [: missing `]'
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 26: [: --version,: binary operator expected
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 27: ]: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 29: Options: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 30: adapter:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 31: alias:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 32: create:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 33: enableHttpd:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 34: name:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 35: path:: command not found
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/hubot/bin/hubot: line 37: `Parser = new OptParse.OptionParser(Switches)'
```

Attempting to install from release package instead of cloning in git results in different errors earlier in the process:

```
root@server:/opt# wget https://github.com/downloads/github/hubot/hubot-2.2.0.tar.gz
root@server:/opt# npm install

npm ERR! Couldn't read dependencies.

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/package.json'
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-3
npm ERR! path /opt/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/package.json'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm not ok
```

I tried `npm cache clean` but it didn't help.

I don't know what to make of it and I'm not very familiar with Hubot or any of the frameworks it runs on, so any information for how to start troubleshooting this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing from [the release package](https://github.com/downloads/github/hubot/hubot-2.2.0.tar.gz) (*Instead of installing from `git clone`*), that solved some random issues for me.

Comment: I tried this, got different errors. Editing op to include info.

Comment: after your wget, you need to unpack the .tgz (gunzip, tar -xvf), it will unpack into a "hubot" directory, then `npm install` in that new directory. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you didn't follow the "Installing dependencies" section of the "Deploying Hubot onto UNIX" link you referenced above.  Specifically, it appears that a regular shell such as bash is trying to interpret the script rather than the coffee-script interpreter.  If you enter

```
coffee
```

at your shell prompt and do not get the

```
coffee>
```

prompt, revisit the first part of the install instructions.

Comment: I did follow the "Installing dependencies" section, and I do get `coffee>` as my prompt when I type `coffee` at my shell prompt. Should I be running my Hubot commands from the `coffee>` prompt?